# How can I concatenate a string with a variable and use it as another variable?

Tags: php, string, variables, variable-variables

I have a variable `$language`, which can be: `"en", "nl", or "fr"`.I have 3  other variables `$menu_en, $menu_fr and $menu_fr`.

I have a php page where I want the menu to appear in any of the 3 languages.

I tried this:

```
echo '$menu_' . $language;
```

What I want is the result to be the value of `$menu_en` and not the string `$menu_nl`.

How can I do this? Can eval() help?

Comment: [Variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker I have a feeling that's not what the OP is asking

Comment: OP: I think you want to do: `echo $menu . $language;`. When you put single quotes around a variable it is not parsed as PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using an `array`?

```
$menu = array("en" => "Hi!", "it" => "Ciao!", "es" => "Hola!");

$language = "en";
echo $menu[$language]; // this will print Hi!
echo $menu["it"]; // will print Ciao!
```

Some ref on arrays: http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use variable variables - like so:

```
$menuVar = 'menu_'.$language;
echo $$menuVar;
```

Note the double dollar signs.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Reversal's suggestion of an array is a better solution.

Comment: The dollar sign in the string is not required and means you'll actually reference a variable who's name begins with a dollar sign.